# 2D array difference in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

I have these two lines of code which I thought would compile both on C and C++.

```
int a[3][3] = {{10,20,30},{40,50,60},{70,80,90}};
int *p[3] = {a+0, a+1, a+2};
```

C compiler compiles it fine. On Visual Studio C++ compiler I get this error:
*error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'int (*)[3]' to 'int *'*

I'm trying to understand what is the difference between these two cases.

Comment: This is the same error in both languages but your compiler is defaulting to different error reporting settings in either case. It is not true that "C++'s type system is stricter than C's"

Comment: Try to raise your warning level: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ziLPtA1Rz2uGPPYe

Comment: Your C compiler should at least warn you about this construct. Raise your warning level for everyone's sake.

Comment: @MiloradP : More importantly, do you understand what the statement does and why there's an error in C++ / warning in C?

Comment: You are probably trying to do this `int *p[3] = {a[0], a[1], a[2]};`.

Comment: Actually, I was confused by a comment on Quora which had this example. To my understanding "a" is a pointer to the whole array, and this looked odd. I quickly ran that on an online compiler, and it worked (and printed exactly what the example showed - 10, 40, 70). Then I tried that on C++ and got an error. Totally forgot that it may be an error hidden by the warning level.

Comment: @MiloradP you misunderstand: `a` is not a pointer at all. `a` is an array.

Comment: @MiloradP C requires only *diagnostics messages* which by default in many C compilers are called warnings due to all sorts of really awful C code floating around that needs to be compilable. The thing is, a C compiler need not compile these programs either, they're **invalid programs** and they can be rejected. But the standard also mentions that a conforming compiler can successfully compile an **invalid program**, provided that it just gives diagnostics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Arrays vs. pointers** is probably one of the harder topics of C (and C++ which inherited that from C). It's actually easy once you understood the concept behind but that concept might be unexpected by starters – I never saw anything similar in other programming languages.

Borgleader told in his comment: <s>`int a[3][3]` decays to `int*`</s> but that's false! (If it were true the issue of OP wouldn't exist.)

The trueth is:

1. `a` is of type `int [3][3]`.
2. `a` may decay to `int (*)[3]` ([a pointer to array 3 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*a%29%5B3%5D))

Hence, the definition of OP has type mismatch errors:

```
int *p[3] = {a+0, a+1, a+2};
```

The elements of `p` have type `int*` but `a+0` (as well as `a+1`, `a+2`) provide an expression of `int (*)[3]`.

This is exactly what clang tells in the [**Live Demo of Bob__ on Wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ziLPtA1Rz2uGPPYe):

```
prog.c:7:18: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int (*)[3]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    int *p[3] = {a+0, a+1, a+2};
                 ^~~
```

Bob__ used C with `-std=c11` and `-pedantic`.

I changed it to C++ with `-std=c++17` and no `-pedantic`. C++ reports this as error because it's by default much stricter concerning type compatibility.

---

> Actually, I was confused by a comment on Quora which had this example.

Considering that C has ever been quite tolerant concerning non-matching types, the example might have worked. To illustrate this, I made a slightly extended example on godbolt.org:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a[3][3] = {{10,20,30},{40,50,60},{70,80,90}};
  int *p[3] = { a + 0, a + 1, a + 2 };
  int *p1[3] = { *(a + 0), *(a + 1), *(a + 2) };
  int *p2[3] = { a[0], a[1], a[2] };
  return 0;
}
```

For `int *p[3] = { a + 0, a + 1, a + 2 };` it compiled:

```
  mov rcx, qword ptr [rbp - 168] # load rcx with address of a
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 80], rcx  # store rcx to p[0] 
  mov rcx, qword ptr [rbp - 168] # load rcx with address of a
  add rcx, 12                    # add 12 to rcx (1 * 3 * sizeof (int))
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 72], rcx  # store rcx to p[1]
  mov rcx, qword ptr [rbp - 168] # load rcx with address of a
  add rcx, 24                    # add 24 to rcx (2 * 3 * sizeof (int))
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 64], rcx  # store rcx to p[2]
```

for `int *p1[3] = { *(a + 0), *(a + 1), *(a + 2) };`:

```
  mov rcx, qword ptr [rbp - 168] # load rcx with address of a
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 112], rcx # store rcx to p1[0]  
  add rcx, 12                    # add 12 to rcx (1 * 3 * sizeof (int))
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 104], rcx # store rcx to p1[1] 
  mov rcx, qword ptr [rbp - 168] # load rcx with address of a
  add rcx, 24                    # add 24 to rcx (2 * 3 * sizeof (int))
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 96], rcx  # store rcx to p1[2]
```

for `int *p2[3] = { a[0], a[1], a[2] };`:

```
  mov rcx, qword ptr [rbp - 168] # load rcx with address of a
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 144], rcx # store rcx to p2[0]  
  add rcx, 12                    # add 12 to rcx (1 * 3 * sizeof (int))
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 136], rcx # store rcx to p2[1] 
  mov rcx, qword ptr [rbp - 168] # load rcx with address of a
  add rcx, 24                    # add 24 to rcx (2 * 3 * sizeof (int))
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 128], rcx # store rcx to p2[2]
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on godbolt**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/t5kVSN)</kbd>

Without going into too much depth, nearly the same code has been produced for all three lines. (The only differences are the addresses after `mov qword ptr [rbp -`... as the initializations are stored into variables which have different addresses on stack, of course.)

It's not that surprising that `*(a + 0)` and `a[0]` result in equivalent code because according to [cppreference: Subscript](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access):

> By definition, the subscript operator `E1[E2]` is exactly identical to `*((E1)+(E2))`.

but even the initialization with pointers of wrong types didn't make a difference.

IMHO, this is good for two lessons:

1. Using correct types by introducing the necessary dereference operators prevents warnings (in C), errors (in C++).
2. Optimizing away dereference operators (at the cost of warnings) doesn't improve the generated binary code.

---

In another comment, the OP stated that

> To my understanding "a" is a pointer to the whole array...

That's wrong. `a` is an array. It may decay to a pointer if required.

That's a difference, and it's easy to illustrate by an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printSizes(int a[3][3], int (*p)[3])
{
  puts("when a and p passed to a function:");
  printf("sizeof a: %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof a);
  printf("sizeof p: %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof p);
}

int main()
{
  int a[3][3] = {{10,20,30},{40,50,60},{70,80,90}};
  int (*p)[3] = { a + 0, a + 1, a + 2 };
  printf("sizeof a: %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof a);
  printf("sizeof p: %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof p);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof a: 36
sizeof p: 8
when a and p passed to a function:
sizeof a: 8
sizeof p: 8
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/pg0XZC)</kbd>

The confusion about arrays and pointers comes probably from the fact that arrays decay in most cases to pointers. Even the subscript operator ([`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Subscript)) is defined for pointers but not for arrays. The `sizeof` operator is one of the few exceptions and shows the difference.

As arrays may not be used as arguments, there is no such difference anymore in function `printSize()`. Even with giving the array type the compiler uses the pointer type resulting from array decay.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Scheff for this detailed explanation. It clears out a lot of confusion. One follow up question though: I still can't seem to grasp the arithmetic of a + 1, a + 2... If "a" is not a pointer to the array as you explained, how this addition works? Does "a" decay to a pointer at this point?

Comment: @MiloradP Same story again. `a` is an array but there is no `operator +` which takes an array and an `int`. Again, `a` decays to a pointer and there _is_ an operator which takes a pointer (of arbitrary type except `void`) and an `int`. (There is even another `operator +` which takes an `int` and a pointer allowing such convoluted things like `0[a]` which resolves to `*(0 + a)` which is identical to `a[0]` or `*(a + 0)`.) Btw. the _type_ in _pointer (of arbitrary type)_ is considered. Hence, `a + 2` multiplies the 2 with the correct size of `a`s element in bytes when calculating the offset.

Comment: @MiloradP "array decays to a pointer" - that's the central thing. Most of operations which look like done on an array are actually available for pointers only. We don't notice this as the compiler inserts an implicit conversion from array to pointer when necessary. In some situations, this implicit conversion has to be considered carefully like in the case where arrays are passed as arguments in function calls. The function will never receive the original array but the pointer to it's first element. In most cases, it makes no difference but in some cases it does e.g. when using `sizeof`.