# when ever i tried to check the size of pointer variable i.e, int *p sizeof(p) then always give 8 bit. Why?

Tags: c++

When I declared an integer array of size 10 and check the size it gives 40 but when I declared integer pointer variable with an array of size 10 and I try to check the size it always gives 8. Why?

```
int A[10];
cout<<sizeof(A)<<endl;  // it gives 40;

int *p;
p = new int[10];
cout<<sizeof(*p)<<endl;  // but it gives always 8;
```

Comment: You said yourself that you're taking the size of a pointer, which is 8. Also there's a big difference between `sizeof(p)` and `sizeof(*p)`. Please clarify which one you're talking about.

Comment: Note: I'm probably looking at a typo here, but just in case... That 8 is bytes, not bits.

Comment: Presumably what you *really* want to do is use `std::vector<int>` and call its `.size()` method (which is in number of elements, not in bits or bytes).

Comment: Your question is wrong. `cout<<sizeof(*p)<<endl` prints the size of `int` which is at least 2 and usually is 4. https://wandbox.org/permlink/R3QvmevmjJLJFN2W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(p)` is always going to be `sizeof(int*)`, which is 8 on your platform.

That does not change regardless of the number of objects you allocate using `new []`.

`A` is of type `int [10]` (an array of 10 `int`s). Its size is `10 * sizeof(int)`.
It makes sense that `sizeof(A)` is 40.

Pointers and arrays are different types. They can be used interchangeably in many use cases but it's also important to know how they are different and where they behave differently. `sizeof` operator is one of the use cases where they are different.

Comment: After having left my upvote, some ad: [SO: 2D array difference in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53029259/7478597). The third part is about sizeof arrays outside and when passed as arguments to functions. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

On a typical 64-bit machine, `sizeof(*p)` should be `4`, while `sizeof(p)` should be `8`.

Hopefully this example clears things up:

```
  int p1[10];
  cout<<sizeof(*p1)<<endl;  // 4 size of the first element (int)
  cout<<sizeof(p1)<<endl;  // 40 size of array (int size * 10)

  int *p2;
  p2 = new int[10];
  cout<<sizeof(*p2)<<endl;  // 4 size of the first element (int)
  cout<<sizeof(p2)<<endl;  // 8 size of the pointer on 64-bit system

  // shows how you're getting the first value by dereferencing
  cout<<*p2<<endl; // 0
  p2[0] = 100;
  cout<<*p2<<endl; // 100
```

Answer (score -2):

Always pointer holds the starting address of an array. Since it's an int pointer, and the size of the int in ur system is 8 bytes, it shows 8 bytes.

Comment: _and the size of the int in ur system is 8 bytes_ That's nonsense. I don't know any system with 64 bit `int`. (In the very past, I had a platform with 16 bit `int` and some embedded systems may still have.) But most important: size of `int` and size of pointers are unrelated. (It wasn't that obvious as long as we compiled 32 bit code but hit me quite hard when we switched to 64 bit.) That's why types like [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) have been introduced.

Comment: Scheff, that's ridiculous. Try the below program yourself and note the pointer address (%d or %p )during each increase (PTR++). Since it's int pointer 4 bytes is increased every time. Same thing is true with char array with just an increase of 1 bytes.

Comment: Try this,. Int arr[5]={10,20,30,40,50} ;. int *PTR,I ;  PTR=&are; for( I=0;I<5;i++){ printf(  *PTR) // for value. Printf( PTR) // for address. U can try similarly for char array.  Ur point is correct only when we use dynamic memory allocation   returning address of the created memory location then casting it to int or char pointer.